# Pulp Scientist Miniaturised Inventions

Tags: d20-modern, d20-past

I'm building a Pulp Scientist in d20 Past, but having some trouble understanding the rules for Inventions (see my other [d20-past](/questions/tagged/d20-past) questions).

According to the Scientist Advanced Class (d20 Past, p84):

> Inventions tend to be bulky, weighing 10 pounds per level of discovery. Held, carried or worn inventions typically take up two body slots, chosen from the list in Chapter Ten of d20 Modern...

But there is a feat to help with that:

> Miniature Invention
>
> Your inventions take up only one body slot, chosen from the following list: head, eyes, back, torso, forearms, left hand, right hand, belt, cape, legs, boots. The level of discovery used in the invention increases by 1. Miniature inventions also weigh only 5 pounds per level of discovery.

My reading of this is that when I get to third level, I can use my second level discovery to create a miniature version of a first level effect. This only takes up one body slot, but is 10 lbs in weight<sup>†</sup>, the same as non miniaturised level 1 effect which takes up two body slots!

#### Is this the correct way of calculating this, or have I misunderstood something?

---

See also my question [Pulp Scientist Invention Feats](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/85087/1658) - If *level of the discovery used* means *level used to create the invention* rather than *discovery slots used up* then this question will have to be rewritten.

<sup>† Discovery level 2 * 5 lbs per discovery level.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Invention Feats

D20 Past says:

> Invention feats function somewhat like the metamagic feats in Urban Arcana and Dungeons & Dragons, in that they allow greater effect by artificially raising the base power level of an invention. By applying an invention feat to a discovery, you increase the level of the discovery (making the invention you're building more expensive), but you gain the benefit listed in the feat.

This section says most of what's necessary to parse what the effects of using the invention feats are. Firstly, and most importantly, they increase the power level of the invention artificially. The effect of this is to make the invention more expensive to craft. Secondarily, they function *somewhat* like metamagic feats. There is no effect regarding this; it's comparison text, not inherited rules. The upshot of this is that unlike with the use of metamagic feats, if you can afford the weight, XP cost and Time or Wealth expenditure, you can build any invention using invention feats that you pay the costs for.

There are *no* Discovery 'slots', just as there are no Spells Known 'slots' in the FX, Urban Arcana, or D&D 3.5 rules. There are merely Spells Known or Discoveries Made. You are limited in how many discoveries of a particular level you can *know*, not in what level of discovery you can *use*. The costs are in the crafting of these inventions, which are *much* like wands in D&D.

The increase in discovery level is related to the Invention they're being used in, not the Discoveries you have made.

---

#### Miniaturized Invention

This feat is *slightly* odd, in that it's somewhat less useful for your lower level discoveries. Applied to your inventions made from 0-level Discoveries, it's almost counterproductive, except to make them only take 1 slot, rather than 2; they'd either weigh exactly what they'd have weighed before, or go from 0-lbs to 5 lbs. Their costs would also increase; by either half again as much, or from a multiplier of 0 to 1.

> These odd statements about 0-level discoveries are due to the fact that d20 Modern does not *explicitly* inherit the 1/2-level multiplier from other d20 products, such as D&D. [This question and answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/85082/how-much-does-a-0-level-invention-weigh/87115#87115) are slightly more verbose regarding this issue. If ruled as multiplying by 0, then the Miniaturized Invention feat is hardly useful beyond making the 0-level item take 1 slot. If using the 1/2-level ruling, then there's a doubling of XP and time/Wealth cost (0.5 multiplier goes to 1), no change in weight (0.5 x10lbs = 1 x5lbs), and a reduction in slot usage.

Here's a list of the effects of miniaturization on weight by level, versus the invention's usual weight. The costs in XP and time/Wealth increase by one multiplier in each case. The slot usage for each invention listed is still reduced from 2 to one.

> - 1st-level: 1 +1 x5lbs =10lbs vs 10lbs
> - 2nd-level: 2 +1 x5lbs =15lbs vs 20lbs
> - 3rd-level: 3 +1 x5lbs =20lbs vs 30lbs
> - 4th-level: 4 +1 x5lbs =25lbs vs 40lbs
> - 5th-level: 5 +1 x5lbs =30lbs vs 50lbs
> - 6th-level: 6 +1 x5lbs =35lbs vs 60lbs*
> - 7th-level: 7 +1 x5lbs =40lbs vs 70lbs*
> - 8th-level: 8 +1 x5lbs =45lbs vs 80lbs*
> - 9th-level: 9 +1 x5lbs =50lbs vs 90lbs*
> - 10th-level: 10 +1 x5lbs =55lbs vs 100lbs*
> - 11th-level: 11 +1 x5lbs =60lbs vs 110lbs*
> - 12th-level: 12 +1 x5lbs =65lbs vs 120lbs*
>
> *These are the weights for miniaturized inventions possible through use of the other invention feats.