# Pulp Scientist Invention Feats

Tags: d20-modern, d20-past

I'm building a Pulp Scientist in d20 Past, but having some trouble understanding the rules for Inventions (see my other [d20-past](/questions/tagged/d20-past) questions).

According to the ***Improvised Invention*** Feat (d20 Past, p85):

> You can construct inventions using discoveries you don’t completely
>   understand.
>
> ***Benefit:*** You can construct an invention using a discovery you
>   don’t have. You must already have one discovery at that level to
>   improvise an invention, so you can’t choose a discovery beyond
>   the levels you have access to. The level of the discovery used in
>   the invention increases by 2.
>
> ***Normal:*** If you don’t have the discovery, you can’t build an
>   invention that uses it.

Depending on how I read this, the feat is either completely useless or really useful.

Lets say I'm a level 5 Scientist, with access to *five* level 1 discoveries and *one* level 3 discovery.

---

Firstly, "*The level of the discovery **used** in the invention increases by 2.*" suggests that I need to use my level 3 discovery in order to create an additional level 1 discovery, which weights three times as much and takes three times as many XP to construct. It also doesn't sound like an improvisation to me.

That doesn't sound like a good deal, when I could just have a level 3 discovery instead.

---

It also doesn't fit with the other part of the ***Benefit*** though which states that "*You must already have one discovery at that level to improvise an invention, so you can’t choose a discovery beyond the levels you have access to.*" Which implies that I don't need to ***use*** a discovery slot at all, I can make as many inventions as I like, as long as I pay the additional XP, weight and construction time cost.

What I mean is, at Scientist level 5 I have one level 3 discovery, so the feat says I should be able to improvise more level three inventions, but obviously I don't have any level 5 discovery slots to *use*, so the rules can't mean that I need to use one, which must mean that I don't need to *use up* a slot at all.

By this interpretation, I can create as many additional level 3 Inventions as I like, but they all weigh 50 lbs rather than 30 lbs, cost 5*5*30XP rather than 3*5*30XP and take 5*5*5 days rather than 3*5*5 days to construct. This seems like a reasonable trade-off.

---

We have a similar problem with the other Invention Feats, which all use exactly the same wording:

- ***Miniature Invention***: *The level of the discovery used in the invention increases by 1.*
- ***Simplified Invention***: *The level of the discovery used in the invention increases by 2.*
- ***Extend Invention***: *The level of the discovery used in the invention increases by 3.*

#### When Discovery Feats specify increased discovery levels, do they take up discovery level slots, or do they just modify the XP, weight and crafting time of the Inventions created?

If *level of the discovery used* means *level used to create the invention* rather than *discovery slots used up* then this also answers my question on problems with [Pulp Scientist Miniaturised Inventions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/85085/1658)

Comment: I don't know enough about the game to put all the pieces together, but Invention Feats says, "By applying an invention feat to a discovery, you increase the level of the discovery (making the invention you're building more expensive), but you gain the benefit listed in the feat" (*d20 Past* 85) , which, if *you* can define *expensive*, may be enough to self-answer.

Comment: It would have been so much easier @HeyICanChan if they had just used the term *discovery* for 'level of the spell being emulated' and *invention* for 'level of the invention after applying Invention Feats', rather than inconsistently and confusingly using them interchangeably, while appearing to mean different things. Sigh.

Comment: Coauthor of *d20 Past* James Jacobs, now Paizo's creative director, has an AMA thread on the Paizo messageboards. He's answered questions there about Wizards of the Coast's *Dungeons and Dragons*-based [*Warcraft III*](https://www.amazon.com/Warcraft-III-Players-Guide-Campaign/dp/0786926651) vaporware; I'm sure if you catch him on a good day, he'll regale you with the *d20 Past* editorial decision-making process (assuming it exists, of course) that's left you in the pickle you're in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Invention Feats

D20 Past says:

> Invention feats function somewhat like the metamagic feats in Urban Arcana and Dungeons & Dragons, in that they allow greater effect by artificially raising the base power level of an invention. By applying an invention feat to a discovery, you increase the level of the discovery (making the invention you're building more expensive), but you gain the benefit listed in the feat.

This section says most of what's necessary to parse what the effects of using the invention feats are. Firstly, and most importantly, they increase the power level of the invention artificially. The effect of this is to make the invention more expensive to craft. Secondarily, they function *somewhat* like metamagic feats. There is no effect regarding this; it's comparison text, not inherited rules. The upshot of this is that unlike with the use of metamagic feats, if you can afford the weight, XP cost and Time or Wealth expenditure, you can build any invention using invention feats that you pay the costs for.

There are *no* Discovery 'slots', just as there are no Spells Known 'slots' in the FX, Urban Arcana, or D&D 3.5 rules. There are merely Spells Known or Discoveries Made. You are limited in how many discoveries of a particular level you can *know*, not in what level of discovery you can *use*. The costs are in the crafting of these inventions, which are *much* like wands in D&D.

---

### Improvised Invention

This feat *greatly* increases your flexibility, but not your power level. The XP, time/Wealth and weight costs tend to balance the benefits of that flexibility. Your known discoveries will be lighter, faster/cheaper to build, and easier for others to use.

The same goes for the other feats in this section of the book; the increase is related to the Invention they're being used in, rather than the Discoveries you've made.

> Interestingly, one could craft an Extended Simplified Create Water Invention as a Level 1 Scientist for 150XP, weighing 50 lbs, and producing 2 gallons/Round (20 Gallons per minute) indefinitely, that anyone could use. Useful for a Fire Brigade, or just to solve the Water Crisis in [Game World Here]

Comment: You can read a passage a dozen times and still not get the implications of what it's saying, so thanks for helping to clarify it.

Comment: @MarkBooth, "Glad to be of service!" he crooned, with a self-satisfied smirk.